# Saving an active record, in what order are the associated objects saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In rails, when saving an active_record object, its associated objects will be saved as well. But has_one and has_many association have different order in saving objects.

I have three simplified models:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  has_one :coach
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  validates_presence_of :team_id
end

class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  validates_presence_of :team_id
end
```

I expected that when `team.save` is called, team should be saved before its associated coach and players.

I use the following code to test these models:

```
t = Team.new
team.coach = Coach.new
team.save!
```

`team.save!` returns true.

But in another test:

```
t = Team.new
team.players << Player.new
team.save!
```

`team.save!` gives the following error:

```
> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
> Validation failed: Players is invalid
```

I figured out that `team.save!` saves objects in the following order: 1) players, 2) team, and 3) coach. This is why I got the error: When a player is saved, team doesn't yet have a id, so `validates_presence_of :team_id` fails in player.

Can someone explain to me why objects are saved in this order? This seems not logical to me.

Comment: To make the problem more explicit: when team.save! is called, is it possible to have the team object saved to database prior to player object?

Answer (score 0):

You should used "validates_associated" to accomplish that

check [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M002171)

Something like following no check though

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  has_one :coach
  validates_associated :players, :coach  ###MOST IMPORTANT LINE 
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  validates_presence_of :team_id
end

class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  validates_presence_of :team_id
end
```

In your controller

```
t = Team.new

@coach = t.build_coach(:column1=> "value1", :column2=> "value2" )  # This create new object with @coach.team_id= t.id
@players = t.players.build

t.save#This will be true it passes the validation for all i.e. Team, COach & Player also save all at once otherwise none of them will get saved.
```

Comment: This still raises ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.

Comment: validates_associated only validates that the associated model is valid in itself, but doesn't validate that the associated model is present. For that, you need validates_presence_of.

See http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.0.beta.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/associated.rb for the full details.

Comment: Can you associate a player with the team? Does that still pass the validation? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Let's look at your failing test:

```
t = Team.new
team.players << Player.new
team.save!
```

Adding a new player to the team.players association tries to set the team_id on players right there on line 2. That's just how the << operator works.  It doesn't get updated when you save team, so even if team is saved first, player still has a null team_id. In this case you can easily solve it by swapping lines 2 and 3.